Registering SIP when receiving a firebase message in terminated flutter app
I'm trying to make a call notification on my flutter app. This is almost working except the following thing. When the app is terminated, I receive the firebase message and I can display my notification, but my SIPController isn't registered so the call is canceled by the server before the user can answer. Do someone know how to handle this ?
This is my main.dart and my SIPController class:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:callkeep/callkeep.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/android_params.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/call_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/call_kit_params.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/ios_params.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/entities/notification_params.dart';
import 'package:flutter_callkit_incoming/flutter_callkit_incoming.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:sip_ua/sip_ua.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/business_logic/services/firebase/diesetel_firebase.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/business_logic/services/sip/sip_controller.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/business_logic/services/sip/sip_listener.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/db/model/utilisateur.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/db/smart_diese_database.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/views/app.dart';

import 'business_logic/utils/assets_manager.dart';

/* Top main variables */
int? initScreen = 0;
final FlutterCallkeep callKeep = FlutterCallkeep();
bool callKeepStarted = false;
final SipUaHelperListener listener = SIPListener();
bool notificationAnswered = false;


class PostHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (
          X509Certificate cert,
          String host,
          int port,
          ) =>
      true;
  }
}

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Message title: ${message.notification?.title}, body: ${message.notification?.body}, data: ${message.data}');
  }
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  await showIncomingCall(message, Uuid().generateV4());
}

Future<void> showIncomingCall(RemoteMessage message, String uuid) async{
  final callerNum = message.data['callerNum'];
  final equipement = await SmartDieseDatabase.instance.readEquipementByNumero(int.parse(callerNum));

  final params = CallKitParams(
    id: uuid,
    nameCaller: equipement.nom,
    avatar: null,
    handle: equipement.numero.toString(),
    textAccept: 'Accept',
    textDecline: 'Decline',
    duration: 30000,
    missedCallNotification: const NotificationParams(
      showNotification: true,
      isShowCallback: false,
      subtitle: 'Missed call',
    ),
    android: const AndroidParams(
      isCustomNotification: true,
      isShowLogo: false,
      incomingCallNotificationChannelName: 'call_channel',
      isShowFullLockedScreen: true,
    ),
    ios: const IOSParams(
      iconName: 'CallKitLogo',
      handleType: '',
      supportsVideo: true,
      maximumCallGroups: 1,
      maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1,
      audioSessionMode: 'default',
      audioSessionActive: true,
      audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
      audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
      supportsDTMF: true,
      supportsHolding: true,
      supportsGrouping: false,
      supportsUngrouping: false,
    ),
  );

  await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
}

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'call_channel',
      'Calls',
      description:
      'This channel is used incoming calls.',
      importance: Importance.high,
      playSound: true
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

Future<void> initFirebase() async {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

  if(initialMessage != null){
    firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(initialMessage);
  }

  FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) {
    if(event!.event == Event.actionCallAccept){
      SIPController.controller.signalAnswer();
    }
    if(event.event == Event.actionCallDecline){
      SIPController.controller.signalHangup();
    }
  });
}

Future<void> main() async {
  HttpOverrides.global = PostHttpOverrides();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs =
  await SmartDieseDatabase.instance.readAllUtilisateur();

  if (utilisateurs.isNotEmpty && utilisateurs[0].role == 0) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    await initFirebase();

    final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    initScreen = preferences.getInt('initScreen');
    await preferences.setInt('initScreen', 1);

    await DiesetelFirebase.initFirebase();
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
  }

  await AssetsManager.initAssets();

  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(const App());
}

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:sip_ua/sip_ua.dart';
import 'package:smart_diese/business_logic/model/sip_model.dart';

class SIPController extends ControllerMVC {
  /* Singleton */
  SIPController._privateConstructor();

  static final SIPController _instance = SIPController._privateConstructor();

  static SIPController get controller => _instance;
  final SIPModel _model = SIPModel();

  void callStateChanged(Call call, CallStateEnum callState) {
    _model.call = call;
    _model.callState = callState;
  }

  String getSipAdress() {
    return _model.call.remote_identity.toString();
  }

  void updateView() {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("REFRESH");
    }
    for (StateMVC<StatefulWidget> element in states) {
      if (element.mounted) element.refresh();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(element.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  void testcall(String contact) {
    _model.testcall(contact);
  }

  void stopHelper() {
    _model.stopHelper();
  }

  void removeSIPListener(SipUaHelperListener l) {
    _model.removeSIPListener(l);
  }

  RegistrationStateEnum? get registerState => _model.registerStatus;
  void register(SipUaHelperListener listener) => _model.register(listener);
  CallStateEnum? get callState => _model.callState;

  void signalAnswer() {
    _model.answerCall();
  }

  void makeCall(String number) {
    _model.makeCall(number);
  }

  void sendREGISTER() {
    _model.sendREGISTER();
  }

  bool isReachable() => _model.isReachable();

  void signalDTMF(String dtmf) {
    _model.sendDTMF(dtmf);
  }

  void signalHangup() {
    _model.hangupCall();
  }

  void signalMuted() {
    _model.call.mute();
  }

  void signalUnmuted() {
    _model.call.unmute();
  }

  void setRegisterState(RegistrationState s) {
    _model.setRegisterStatus = s;
    updateView();
  }
}


When the app is terminated it has already lost connection with SIP server and SIPController is not running.
Current implementation just displays notification, but doesn't restore SIP connection and can't receive call.
When push notification received its handler should start app first (it will proceed regular initialization, make connection to SIP server and receive SIP call) and only after that display some notification.
iOS app can be started only by PushKit + VoiP push token and has to display CallKit UI immediately after receiving push (start).
Check also timeout on the server side, how long it's waiting after sending push and before cancel call.
